# combine two vectors with comman element in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors `ord1=c(1,2)` and `ord2=c(3,1)`. how can I combine these vectors to get the output `3 1 2` in R? in other words, I have directions 1 to 2 `(1--> 2)`and 3 to 1 `(3-->1)` but finally I want to get the direction `3-->1-->2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have only two vectors and no direction is repeated then below code may serve the purpose.

```
ord1 <- paste(ord1, collapse = '')
ord2 <- paste(ord2, collapse = '')

if (substr(ord1, 1, 1) == substr(ord2, nchar(ord2), nchar(ord2))) {
  Direction <- paste(ord2, substr(ord1, 2, nchar(ord1)), sep = '')
} else if (substr(ord1, nchar(ord1), nchar(ord1)) == substr(ord2, 1, 1)) {
  Direction <- paste(ord1, substr(ord2, 2, nchar(ord2)), sep = '')
} else {
  Direction <- 'No continuous direction found'
}

Direction

[1] "312"
```

Both vectors can be of different sizes but same direction can't be repeated. If for some reason complete sequence is missing then code with return output as ***No continuous direction found***

Answer (score -1):

You just combine the two vectors using the direction you prefer, and then find the unique elements.

```
unique(c(ord2, ord1))
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. I want to detect direction automatically. I just have the information ord1=c(1,2) and ord2=c(3,1) so I want to use a function that detect automatically that the correct direction between them that is 3-->1-->2